# Error when trying to connect to Anypoint Platform from Studio 7. There was a problem with the SSL handshake

Tags: api, ssl-certificate, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-platform

Error when trying to connect to Anypoint Platform from Studio 7. There was a problem with the SSL handshake, please check your certificate installation

There was a problem with the SSL handshake, please check your certificate installation.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I am stuck on this issue since month, please help..

Comment: What are you doing when this message appears? Is something not working correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please post the lines of code where this issue occurs.

Comment: Is this a code issue? Have you checked that the certificate you are accessing isn't expired? Dou you have the CA root certificate of the offending certificate in your keystore?

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming you are using AnypointStudio 7.6.0, it comes with AdoptOpenJDK8 bundled.  If not, install AdoptOpen JDK.  Next, create a JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to your OpenJDK install location.
2. Use a browser to access https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/ and check the Certificate details in the "Certificate Path" tab. So at this point, follow the method that you used to install i.e. *import* not only **Company Root CA** certificate but also add **Company Issuing CA Intranet Server** certificate (this is the child of the Company Root CA) details to the stand-alone JVM that you installed. This is important for your Studio to work properly.

See some more details here: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-resolve-certification-error-when-performing-update-in-Studio